# Python - Returning only first value from a for loop statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I know this is basic but I have not been able to break this. I have a `for loop` that I am trying to execute that returns back 10 rows. How do I limit the loop to only return back **first row** and not the entire output.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

I cannot change the range value from 10.

Current output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Expected output :

```
0
```

Comment: Please provide a little bit more code/context

Comment: why would you initiate a loop at first place if you need only first value?

Comment: @VladimirVishnevskyi I am running through a list of files in a folder but I only want the first file extracted and hence I am trying this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `break` statement would do:

```
for i in range(10): 
    print(i) 
    break
```

Comment: Using `break` never struck me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break`:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    break
```

And this is not returning anything, it just print the value out.

Comment: Using `break` never struck me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can break out of the loop:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    break
```

Comment: Using `break` never struck me. Thanks.